# How to read a ConnectionString from appsettings.json in a Razor Pages Project

Tags: c#, connection-string, razor-pages, appsettings, configurationmanager

My `appsettings.json` looks like:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "TestDB": {
          "ConnectionString": "Server=TheServer;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;",
          "ProviderName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
}
```

And I am trying to access the Connection String with:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbName].ConnectionString;
```

This throws a Null Exception error and I am unsure as to why.

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) help?

Comment: @GuruStron I'm getting an error; CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDbContext' and no accessible extension method 'AddDbContext' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found

Comment: @OliverGuy This is absolutely different error. It seems you've forgotten to add entity framework NuGet packages or just `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

Comment: @Agrgg I have got `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` added

Comment: @OliverGuy Then make sure you've added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Nuget packages.

Comment: @Agrgg Unistalled and reinstalled the package and now it working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ConfigurationManager` is outdated, you need to use `IConfiguration` in .NET Сore environment (`IConfiguration` is provided by .NET Core built-in dependency injection).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66126674/3100967) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what user @Agrgg said:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66658317/3712531

> ConfigurationManager is outdated, you need to use IConfiguration in .NET Сore environment (IConfiguration is provided by .NET Core built-in dependency injection).

```
    private readonly IConfiguration config;

    public MyConstructor(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }
    public void DoSomethingFunction()
    {
        string settings1 = config["Setting1"];
    }
```